# Trouble cloning a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, cloning

```
    def add_column(matrix):
"""
  >>> m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
  >>> add_column(m)
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  >>> n = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
  >>> add_column(n)
  [[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
  >>> n
  [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
"""
new_matrix = matrix[:]
for row in new_matrix:
    row += [0]
return new_matrix
```

Doctests to return the original matrix will return the new matrix, I'm not sure how to clone this matrix without editing the original.

Comment: You need to use deepcopy

Answer (score 1):

You are making a copy of the outer list, but each inner list is still the same.  You need to use a different list for `row` instead of modifying it:

```
new_matrix = []
for row in matrix:
    new_matrix.append(row + [0])
```

A condensed version of that is:

```
new_matrix = [row + [0] for row in matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because the matrix is represented as a list of lists. The statement `new_matrix = matrix[:]` makes a copy of the "outer" list but does not make a copy of each row. Your implementation is also known as a shallow copy. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) for a more detailed explanation.

You can either implement the `add_column` method following zondo's suggestion, use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module to create a deep copy, or use `numpy`. Although using `numpy` requires you to get to know a new library, the flexibility and computational efficiency is worth it in the long run.